# Estimating variables from noisy nonlinear equations

Tags: nonlinear-system, noise

I'm trying to solve for two scalar variables from a set of non-linear equations of the form:

$a_i\cos(x)+b_i\sin(x)=y$

Where $x,y$ are the variables, and $a_i,b_i$ with $i=1..n$ are noisy measurements.  Obviously, if one ignores the noise, 2 equations are enough.

What approach can be used to minimize the effect of the noise using all the equations?

Comment: By dividing by cos(x) you can make this look like a linear regression in the two constants y/cos(x) and -tan(x).  Strictly speaking it is not a linear regression because $a_i$ and $b_i$ will both have measurement error. Hope this moves you forward.

Comment: Actually, I found that if the equations are formulated in matrix form, it can be transformed to a quadratic equality constraint, quadratic programming problem, which should have a solution in this case.